# Updating a Date Field with Last Day of The Month based on another Date Field

Tags: workflow, formula, formula-field

Updating a Date Field with Last Day of The Month based on another Date Field.

I need to write a formula to do a field update when an Implementation is complete.

Basically once it's marked as complete I need a field update that will set a date field called `Billing_To_Begin_Date__c` with the last day of the month from another field called `MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c`.

For example, the implemntation is marked complete, the `MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c = March 2, 2016` then the `Billing_To_Begin_Date__c becomes March 31, 2016`

Can anyone help me accomplish this? I have the WFR created but need help with the formula to set that last day of the month. Below is what I had but it is not working as expected:

```
DATE 
( 
YEAR( MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c ) + 1, 
Month( MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c ), 
CASE( MONTH(MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c), 
1, 31, 
2, IF( MOD( YEAR(MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c) + 1, 4) = 0,29, 28), 
3, 31, 
4, 30, 
5, 31, 
6, 30, 
7, 31, 
8, 31, 
9, 30, 
10, 31, 
11, 30, 
12, 31, 
0 
) 
)
```

Comment: It seems like the only problem is you are adding 1 to year? What do you mean not working as expected?

Comment: I thought you'd posted before. Is this formula still broken?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula works fine for me. Just replace all instances of

```
YEAR(MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c) + 1
```

with

```
YEAR(MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c)
```

Sample input/output combos:

```
03-02-2016 / 03-31-2016
02-02-2016 / 02-29-2016
01-02-2016 / 01-31-2016
12-02-2015 / 12-31-2015
```

Comment: Adrian -- a typo on the last example?  `12-02-2015` sb `12-02-2016`

Comment: Yep delicious copy pasta. @cropredy

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do this: rather than trying to actually figure out which is the last day of the month, find out the first day of the next month and subtract a day:

```
IF(
  MONTH( MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c ) = 12,
  DATE( YEAR( MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c ), 12, 31 ),
  DATE( YEAR( MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c ), MONTH ( MostRecent_Actual_Install_Date__c ) + 1, 1 ) - 1 
)
```

This and more tips on working with dates and times in Salesforce formulas may be found in [Using Date, Date/Time and Time Values in Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5) and [Sample Date Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5) in Salesforce Help.